# After I edited my nginx's nginx.conf,and execute test command, an command not found error appeared

Tags: java, nginx

Today I executed  `/use/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf -t to nginx`, but it showed the following error:

```
[root@ddqcsAPP ~]# /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf -t
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 3: worker_processes: command not found 
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 9: pid: command not found 
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 12: events: command not found 
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 13: worker_connections: command not found 
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token }' 
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 14: }'
```

The last time I remembered I can executed it with success. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: [root@ddqcsAPP ~]# /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf -t
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 3: worker_processes: command not found
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 9: pid: command not found
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 12: events: command not found
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 13: worker_connections: command not found
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 14: `}'

Comment: not related to java I think.

Comment: }' /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf: line 14: }'

Comment: @PascalHeraud I'm not sure,because I saw some answer is about php application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Java related. You are trying to use the nginx config-checking option, but you are using it wrong.

You should simply call `nginx -t` (the nginx command) to test your config, not trying to run the actual config file. :)